# Are google cloud functions executed only in America?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to know if I can change where the function is executed. So far, I have not been able to choose which region's server executes the function, and I have not found any reference to this in the documentation. My american users have low latencies (2-3 seconds), whereas european users have 7+ second delays. It really hurts the usability of my product.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet? I am trying to find out when the Cloud Functions are planned to be available in Europe

Comment: @Hacktisch According to this https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/, they cloud functions are only executed in America. No clue when they will be available in Europe. Maybe try Amazon Lambda instead, it has servers in Ireland.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked a new question about plans on expanding to other regions https://serverfault.com/questions/858348/cloud-functions-plans-for-availability-in-other-regions

Comment: Still impossible to execute cloud function in Europe ..

Comment: I have tried execution of cloud functions with every europe-west* region, even though the source code is stored in europe, execution is still in america to this day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cloud Functions are currently available in the following non-US regions:

- europe-west1 (Belgium)
- europe-west2 (London)
- asia-east2 (Hong Kong)
- asia-northeast1 (Tokyo)
- europe-west3 (Frankfurt)

See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations for more details.